# Best possible way to perform calculations on a long series of succeeding columns in a select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table that keeps payments for different employees, each week, along with some other data.

For example

```
Employee ID  | Upper Limit | ... | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week .. | ... | Week 52 | isActive |
8971239        70000               100      200      100      400             500       1
7823468        60000               200      300      100      200             400       1
8187119        20000               300      300      300      300             200       1
```

When I am needing to calculate e.g. the SUM of all weeks for a specific employee,
in order to avoiding writing the below code:

```
SELECT [Week 1] + [Week 2] + [Week 3] + ... + [Week 52] FROM tblWeeklySalaries where EmployeeID = 8971239
```

I am creating a string inside a loop that will be used as a script to be executed.
Something like this:

```
DECLARE @script nvarchar(max)
SET @script = 'SET @periodou = (SELECT '

WHILE @tempWeek <= @week
BEGIN

    IF @tempWeek <= 52
    BEGIN
        SET @script = @script + 'ISNULL([Week ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @tempWeek) + '], 0) +'  
    END
    SET @tempWeek = @tempWeek + 1
END

SET @script = LEFT(@script, LEN(@script) - 1)
SET @script = @script + ' AS [Salary] FROM tblWeeklySalaries 
                                      WHERE [EmployeeID ] = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @EmployeeID)
```

However I am not fond of this way, since creating a string is not easily handled and many times it gets extremely complicated in more demanding scripts.

Thus I am looking for a way to add e.g. a series of columns in a specific table.
Something like

```
SELECT (COLUMNS(4, 56) FROM INFORMATION.SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblWeeklySalaries') FROM tblWeeklySalaries where EmployeeID = 8971239
```

Any advice?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like you need to fix your design. You shouldn't have 52 columns called `Week N` (where `N` is the week number), you should have a column called `Week`, which stores the week number, and a column to store the value. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: Simply [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) your data.

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the first normal form by prosthesis… The consequencies will be:

- difficulties for writing queries
- important loss of performances
- transaction anomalies

The fact you have multiples columns call "Week...*n*" means that you want multiples values **for the same information**, which differs by one criteria.

In facts, this could be replaced by an Array of weeks limited from 1 to 52.
But the first normal form says that you should Always have only ATOMIC values in a column.
ARRAYS contains multiple values, by consequent they are not atomic.
You have a hidden array by using such a structure of your table. 
This i a tipicall violation of the first normal form by prosthesis…

In designing correctly your database :

```
CREATE TABLE T_EMPLOYEE_PAYS 
(EMP_ID,    YEAR,    WEEK_NUMBER,    SALARY)
```

The query will be very quick to write :

```
SELECT EMP_ID,  YEAR,  SUM(SALARY)
FROM   T_EMPLOYEE_PAYS 
GROUP  BY EMP_ID,  YEAR
```

ANd yout will have no trouble to index it for performances and no loss of data in transactions.

Remember that a relational database is not a Spreadsheet

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree on the matter.

However this is legacy code and not a DB I designed.
The system goes decades back and unfortunately does not bring enough money for the company I work for, in order to justify redesigning it. 

I am only asking if I could somehow improve at least the existing functionality and create cleaner more understandable code. Script many times last multiple, multiple lines and thus become unreadable and unsupportable...

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lousy data structure and should fix it.  A SQL table should almost never have repeated columns.  Putting the values in separate rows is much simpler.

In any case, you can write a view to do this efficiently using `apply`:

```
create view v_WeeklySalaries as
    select ws.employee_id, . . . ,  -- other columns you want from tblWeeklySalaries
           v.*      
    from tblWeeklySalaries ws cross apply
         (values ('Week 1', ws.[Week 1]),
                 ('Week 2', ws.[Week 2]),
                 . . . 
         ) v(week, salary);
```

You can then use this view.  You might need to recreate the view every week -- it is unclear in your data model how new weeks are added.  At least, you'll need to do that until you fix your data model.

Comment: This is the answer I would have given, but I will add a little trick : If the table is redesign, the view must be redisigned too. In this cas use a DDL trigger that catch ALTER TABLE and filter on this table to modify the view too